# When using the abbreviation etc., should it be parenthetical, i.e. enclosed between commas?

Tags: commas, abbreviations, etc

I was re-reading *The Elements of Style* when I noticed a remark I had previously overlooked in the third rule of usage (*Enclose parenthetic expressions between commas.*).

> The abbreviations *etc.*, *i.e.*, and *e.g.*, the abbreviations for academic degrees, and titles that follow a name are parenthetic and should be punctuated accordingly.
>
> Eg: Letters, packages, etc., should go here.

I understand why the other abbreviations are parenthetical, but am not convinced whether *etc.* should be parenthetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of existing question found at: [When Putting etc. in the middle of a sentence...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283086/when-putting-etc-in-the-middle-of-a-sentence-do-you-use-etc-or-etc-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Etc.* is parenthetical by definition: it provides incidental or supplementary information, not definitional.  It means *and other things*, and if you wrote it out, you'd enclose the phrase in commas, wouldn't you? Whether it should be enclosed by commas in running text is a matter of style, and you should be guided by your manual of style, either the one you've chosen or one thrust upon you. You've apparently chosen Strunk and White. If it helps, the *Chicago Manual of Style* agrees with S&W, although it says the usage should be discouraged.